# Controller Receiving Errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the controller itself loading properly however I don't think I have my controller written correctly according to the documentation for the wiredesignz moduler extentions codeigniter framework plugin. Reason I'm saying I might not have written it properly is because I'm receiving plenty of errors.

Errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$data

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 58
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Indirect modification of overloaded property Quotes::$data has no effect

Filename: controllers/quotes.php

Line Number: 71
```

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Quotes extends MX_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('kowauth');

}

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array(); //msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = ''; //If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = ''; //If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = ''; //Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = ''; //alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    // Checks to see if a session is active for user and shows corresponding view page
    if ($this->kowauth->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $bodyContent = "testing"; //which view file
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
    $bodyType = "full"; //type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.
    if (count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show',
            'msgs' => $msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if ($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons; //if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons; //if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons; //if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags(); //defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle; //defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->data['userData'] = $this->users->getUserByUserID($this->session->userdata('userID'));
    $roster = $this->kowauth->getRosterList($this->data['userData']->usersRolesID);
    $userRoster = array();
    foreach ($roster AS $member)
    {
        $userRoster[$member->id] = $member->rosterName;
    }
    $this->data['userRoster'] = $userRoster;
    $this->data['personalMessages'] = array($this->pmmodel->
        getInboxUnreadMessagesCount($this->session->userdata('userID')), $this->pmmodel->
        getInboxMessagesCount($this->session->userdata('userID')), $this->pmmodel->
        getLast5Messages($this->session->userdata('userID')));
    $this->load->view('cpanel/index', $this->data);
}
}

/* End of file quotes.php */
/* Location: ./application/modules/bios/controllers/quotes.php */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the modular extension but it looks as though the error is you are trying to asign values to $this->data without having created $this->data

Try adding this and see what happens

```
class Quotes extends MX_Controller
{
    public $data;
```

Comment: This is odd because all of this code is the general template for my regular controllers that reside in the application/controllers folder and I don't receive any errors like this in any of those.

Comment: It's not something I've used personally, You could also try creating an array $data, setting all those values to that array and then passing that. So $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes; would be $data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes, and $this->load->view('cpanel/index', $this->data); would become $this->load->view('cpanel/index', $data);

Comment: The answer is actually that I should use CI instead of MX in the extends of the controller. I guess I don't quite understand some of the plugin.

Comment: Aha! Well spotted sir, I assumed (through my not using that extension) that you were doing it right, and the issue was with the $this->data. Hi5 for fixing it :)

Comment: Thank you for responding though.